# How to set Lucene standard analyzer for PhraseQuery search?

Tags: lucene

I'm under the impression from a variety of tutorials out there on Lucene that if I do something like:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexPath, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

Document doc = new Document();
Field title = new Field("title", titlefield, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
doc.add(title);
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.optimize();
writer.close();

IndexReader ireader = IndexReader.open(indexPath);
IndexSearcher indexsearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);

Term term1 = new Term("title", "one");
Term term2 = new Term("title", "two");
PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
query.add(term1);
query.add(term2);
query.setSlop(2);
```

that Lucene should return all queries for the title field containing "one" and "two" within 2 words of each other. But I don't get any results because I'm not using the StandardAnalyzer to search. How can do a proximity search in Lucene then? Does the following queryParser allow for proximity searches (using the tilde?)

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("title",new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = queryParser.parse("test");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, when you parse a query using QueryParser you will be able to do proximity searching.

In general it is always recommended to use the same analyser for indexing and searching.

BR,

Chris